# mono mkbundle utility on windows

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, mono

There has been a fair amount of mention of the Mono utility mkbundle which is supposed to (among other things) allow you to create a bundle (standalone .exe) with a C# project compiled with Mono.  This works when I run it in Cygwin, however what I really would like to do is use the `--deps` option and `--static` option to pull in all of the dependencies and libraries so that it really is a standalone.  While running the command in Cygwin, it claims that `--static` is unsupported under the current platform (I assume it is referring to windows).  The question, then is :

Is there any way around this dilemma?

If not, what specific .dlls am I now required to carry along with my executable in order to get the thing running?  It doesn't seem to be listed anywhere on the mono site.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK only managed (.net) assembly are supported.
Non managed assemblies are some or other way related os.

Answer (score 5):

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkbundle:

> On Windows systems, it it necessary to
>   have Unix-like toolchain to be
>   installed for mkbundle to work. You
>   can use cygwin's and install gcc,
>   gcc-mingw and as packages.
>   (sic)

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to make a crossplatform app in mono with all necessary libraries included because these libraries will rely on some specific non-managed libraries.
 The right way here is to create an installer ([using wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) for example) for your application and include a mono installer in it. So when you'll install your app the mono will be installed too. For linux you'll need to create an installer too.

Comment: Actually, that isn't true. I think you mean "no way to make a cross platform bundled app".