# c# app compiled using mono on windows for a zero install solution?

Tags: c#, windows, mono

HI,

I have a simple~ish command line app written in c#.  I now need to use this on a server where I cannot install the dot net framework.

If I compile the app in Mono - will I be able to use it on a Windows server without the .net framework installed and without installing any mono-related files?

Hopefully just drop the exe in - and it will work?

MoMA (The mono migration analyzer) says the app is compatible with Mono.

Thanks

FrankB

Comment: I am glad the solution worked for you. Did you deviate at all from that guideline? If so, could you share the details with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321207/how-to-convert-a-simple-net-console-project-a-into-portable-exe-with-mono-and-mk/1321292#1321292). I haven't performed the operation myself, but it may be of some help to you.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give this a crack tomorrow, and feedback my results.