# Mono exe asks for mscoree.dll

Tags: .net, mono

Compiled my .net 2.0 project, under mono 2.4 profile in vs2010.

Running executable on win2k whitout .net framework.

Getting error: can not find mscoree.dll

How can I solve it?

Comment: Install .Net Framework. Or run with Mono: `mono.exe myapp.exe`.

Comment: need to deploy app by xcopy, if i could install .net framework, i wouldnt use mono

Comment: Then read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321207/how-to-convert-a-simple-net-console-project-a-into-portable-exe-with-mono-and-m

Comment: Did you actually start the app with `mono yourapp.exe`?

Comment: i dont have neither mono or .net on client machine, need portable solution

Comment: @JackBrown: If you dont have mono or .NET, how on earth do you expect it to run???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect a .Net program to run on windows (or any other platform for that matter) without a CLR like Mono or .Net.

You can however use the mono mkbundle program to produce a single binary statically linked with the mono runtime and with your assemblies packed inside. It is not really intended for windows use but I think it should work.

[mkbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948113/mono-mkbundle-windows) also has license issues, as you end up including a static copy of mono ( which is GPL ) inside. So you should take note of this if you are considering third-party distribution.

Comment: In hindsight, mkbundle on windows is even more pointless as you'll then need cygwin