# Is C# code compiled to native binaries?

Tags: c#, compilation, bytecode

I know that Java code is compiled into byte-code, that is executed by the JVM.

What is the case with C# ? I have noticed that applications written in C# have the `.exe` extension what would suggest they are native machine instructions. but is it really so ?

Comment: This should explain. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages

Comment: With ngen (alike Java with jit)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No.

Like Java, C# is compiled to an intermediary language (called MSIL or CIL).

Unlike Java, the IL is stored in EXE files which have enough actual EXE code to show a dialog box asking users to install .Net.

Comment: Mm. Bit confusing to just say "No" to "Is C# code compiled". Obviously, it is compiled. Into CLI instructions. Just not (directly) into native code. Obviously, in the end they _are_ (just-in-time) compiled to native code, anyways.

Comment: @sehe: I'm saying "no" to the last line in the question.

Comment: I've edited the question title to avoid the mismatch there :)

Comment: It's not that simple. There is `ngen` and GAC.

Comment: Okay. Does C# then take any advantage of being stored in an EXE or being developed by the same company as the OS? Short: is C# faster than Java?

Comment: @Queequeg it is as fast as it needs to be. If you are having a slow down, run a profiler and identify the problem, don't just blame the language.

Comment: @SK-logic So.. is it possible to compile C# to native binary? For instance, in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Queequeg, use `ngen` for pre-compiling your assemblies into native code.

Comment: But can it be a default behavior, can I really make a standalone executable that will run on a Windows machine that doesnt have .net installed?

Answer (score 6):

C# compilation is done in these two steps :

```
1. Conversion from C# to CIL by the C# compiler

2. Conversion from CIL to instructions that the processor can execute.
```

A component (just in time) performs this compilation at run time from CIL to machine code

Answer (score 6):

What that .exe is supposed to tell you is that the file is executable. C# is compiled into bytecode, just as java is, but .NET wraps this in a CLR executable.

Look here for a more in depth look at CLR executable http://etutorials.org/Programming/.NET+Framework+Essentials/Chapter+2.+The+Common+Language+Runtime/2.2+CLR+Executables/

Comment: The term Portable Executable is not just specific to .NET.

Answer (score 5):

c# code is compiled to MSIL. it likes java bytecode. msil will be convert to machine isntrctions at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

C# code is compiled to MSIL, MSIL is taken care by .NET CLR

Answer (score 0):

There is also a project that allows compilation of C# to standalone binary executables: [CoreRT](https://github.com/dotnet/corert)