# mono mkbundle and cyrillic paths

Tags: mono, mkbundle

I'm bundling Mono with my WinForms application on Windows using mkbundle utility. I've followed procedure described here: [Can not compile simple C# application with mkbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474613/can-not-compile-simple-c-sharp-application-with-mkbundle). Application builds and runs just fine, but only if path to executable does not contain cyrillic symbols. If path contain such symbols (folder names in russian etc.) application doesn't start at all (no error messages displayed). It seems that problem occurs before managed code is run. Is it any way to diagnose and fix such a problem? I don't have experience with C code, so I can't figure what should be changed in host.c file or GCC options.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set MONO_EXTERNAL_ENCODING variable in host.c (in main method), produced by mkbundle:

```
SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_EXTERNAL_ENCODINGS", "UTF16");
```

Comment: this way working on me. but the bundled application can'not get AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory on non-ansi path  .any ideas?