# Problems while creating a Linux-executable file from C# sourcecode using mkbundle

Tags: c#, linux, mono, debian, mkbundle

As mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668126/i-have-a-program-in-c-sharp-can-i-compile-it-as-an-executable-for-linux-server) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686049/c-sharp-program-doesnt-work-under-mono-in-linux) I am using `mkbundle -o newfile oldfile.exe --static` (OS: Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, Mono: 2.10.5) to create a file which shall be executable on an Apache Web Server (OS: Debian GNU/Linux 32bit). Here, the `oldfile.exe` was the result of the compilation of a C#-Hello-World-Code using `mcs oldfile.cs`. On the original system (with Ubuntu) the file is executable. However, whenver I call `newfile` on the Apache Web Server I get the error:

> cannot execute binary file

Also, when doing `file newfile` it says

> ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped

I suspect if mkbundle worked as it is supposed to, then it should have read

> ... statically linked ...

shouldn't it? Anyone an idea why the file is not executable on the Server? Is it a problem because of 32bit/64bit?

Comment: I call the application with PHP using `./newfile` or `sh newfile`. I have tried both these options with the three PHP-commands `exec/passthru/system`. Every time the same error `cannot execute binary file` occurs (I read the errors out in the apache-error-log).

Comment: Can you show `file newfile`? Is your server system 32bit?

Comment: Good idea. The output of `file newfile` on the server is   `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped` . As for the server system, I have to find out if it is 32 or 64bit and will get back with that info. When I use the same command on the building machine (Ubuntu) it gives the same plus `for GNU/Linux 2.6.15`. Perhaps, mkbundle didn't do what I wanted it to, i.e. didn't include all the linked libraries into one file?!

Comment: According to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) the server has a 32bit kernel, while I use the mkbundle-command on a 64bit kernel. May this be the problem? I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mkbundle` from 64-bit Mono generates 64-bit executables and you cannot run a 64-bit executable on 32-bit kernel. As `mkbundle` doesn't have an option to generate 32-bit binaries you apparently need to generate your executable with 32-bit Mono (theoretically you can install 32-bit Mono on your 64-bit system but that is not very easy so I suggest installing a 32-bit system somewhere, maybe in VM).

Comment: Yes, basically mkbundle relies on embedding the static or shared library that makes up part of the runtime you are using.