# Making Mono and Mkbundle turn C# code into executable file for target system?

Tags: c#, php, linux, apache, mono

**My goal:** Writing some C#-code, compile it, and run it at the target server (Apache Web Server, OS: Debian GNU/Linux 32bit) using PHP-command `passthru("newfile",...)`.

**Now:** Based on the advice I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213098/problems-while-creating-a-linux-executable-file-from-c-sharp-sourcecode-using-mk) I did compile my C#-code with Mono and did create a 32bit Linux-executable file (on my Ubuntu 11.10 32bit system) using

> mkbundle -o newfile oldfile.exe --static

However, when calling this `newfile` via PHP it doesn't give the expected return value "Hello World", but the number `1`.

**Questions:** Am I using mkbundle wrongly? How can I find out where the problem lies?

**Additional info:** Writing `file newfile` on the target system gives

> newfile: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped

My C#-code is a simple Hello-World program printing `Hello World` into the console. The PhP command I use is `<?php passthru("./newfile", $temp);   echo "$temp"; ?>`
The return value I get from this PhP-file is simply `1`. The Apache log files show no error.

Comment: How do you call it in PHP, and did you make it a console application that prints to Console?  Please post calling PHP code and some C# if possible.  Thanks

Comment: I use the PHP commands `passthru("./newfile", $temp); echo "$temp";`. And yes, it is a console application which prints to Console the words `Hello World`. I included this info in my post which was a pain because of alleged formatting mistakes.

Comment: If you try and run your newfile program on the source system, does it work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it does work perfectly.

Comment: You should also use the --deps option in mkbundle. Static only links the mono runtime, you need the assemblies as well.